# jQuery toggle works once only

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of buttons, class="flipper", used to toggle the show/hide and disabled state of another element.  THAT part works without a problem. But when I try to toggle the .text value of the button itself, it changes the first time, then sticks in the secondary state and won't budge.

```
 $.fn.toggleLabel = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this.text());
        if ($this.text('Enter your Own')) {
            $this.text('Select from DropDown');
        } else {
            $this.text('Enter your Own');
        }
    });
    };


          $('.flipper').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();           
            $(this).nextAll().toggleDisabled();
            $(this).toggleLabel();
          });
```

I threw the console.log in there to check the state of $this.text, and sure enough, every subsequent time the button is clicked, the .text value is 'Select from DropDown'.

Why isn't the conditional in the toggleLabel function catching this, and changing the value back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional `if` isn't doing what you think it is.

It is actually setting the text each time to `'Enter your Own'` and returns a jQuery object which will always be truthy. Since it is truthy, the first expression will always be invoked setting it to `'Select from DropDown'`

Change

```
if ($this.text('Enter your Own'))
```

To

```
if ($this.text() === 'Enter your Own'))
```

Comment: @charlietfl--THANK you! That worked--and thanks also for the explanation of WHY it wasn't working.  If I could up-vote you twice for being kind enough to explain, I would--but they don't have that...:)